# (Wordpress) PinPoint Booking plugin shows blank in admin panel

Tags: wordpress

I've resently installed wordpress, and I installed pinpoint booking system as well.

When I installed it, it gave me an error, but it's simply showed up unactivated in 'plugins'.

When I activate it, and visit its settings, the screen is blank, where settings should be.

I increased my memory to 512 by doing this in config.php:

```
/** Memory Limit */
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
```

Still same result, a blank screen.

Can anybody tell me a way to fix it?

Comment: yes delete it, should be fixed!  Sorry for that but we get tons of questions that don't provide any information that could fix it and are actually irrelevant as not about specific code despite the prompts when writing the question to provide this information. Probably the best thing to do here is ask on the plugin forum page, the author will be more interested in issues with the plugin than we will be.

Comment: Well, i'm interested in getting it fixed, so why don't you ask for what you need. I'm a rookie, i didn't even star learning php yet, so difficult to figure out what i should post. Thought this problem might have been fixed by showing up in another plugin maybe. Was in touch with the author of the plugin, he told me to increase as descibed. So i did, and it didn't help.

Comment: well go back to him, its his code what you are asking is impossible to solve without the error causing the white screen. My advice is to choose a different plugin. But if you persist, turn on php errors in php.ini and that is a start. But you need to learn php and trying to learn with a full plugin and trying to understand is very hard.